# SignalR: How to force disconnect/reconnect from server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a web application that uses frames. The signalr hub runs in one of the frames. When working in the application, the frame with the hub code is not refreshed. This works well, until the session is lost (user logging out or some other reason). The frame with the hub code is not refreshed, so from what I can see, the connection is associated to an old group (I use sessionid as the group name), so I need to force a connect/reconnect from the server to connect the new group with the client.

One method I think should work, would be to create a client method that I call from the server(session_end) that starts and stops the connection. Another solution could be to create a client method that refreshes the frame with the hub code.

Any other suggestions on how to best handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your first suggestion of creating a client method to be called from the server when the session is lost is probably the simplest solution. The client method can easily force a reconnect.

I wonder if you need to reconnect at all though. You say are using a sessionid as the group name. I assume you are referring to SignalR groups. Why can't you simply add the existing connection with the lost session to the appropriate new group/sessionid (i.e. the group the client would be added to if it had reconnected)?